# How can I create a copy button directly from same button Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have a code like this in VueJs:

```
methods: {
   copyUrl(data) {
      console.log(data);
      data.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
   }
}
```

My button is:

```
 <button v-on:click="copyUrl('1234')" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm">
     <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
 </button>
```

I wonder how can I copy the 1234? I mean I need to create a url copy button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass data to the function, try something like below

```
methods: {
  copyUrl() {
   var cpLink = window.location.href;
   cpLink.select();
   try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
   }
   event.preventDefault; 
 }
}
```

Comment: @Amaarockz and how can I fix the button ? I mean  <button v-on:click="copyUrl('1234')" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm">

Comment: In button just make it as `v-on:click="copyUrl" `

Comment: Check the edited answer